# How to split text using two separators in lua?

Tags: split

I have text = "one, two, three and four"
What pattern i have to use to split it like that:

```
one
two
three
four
```

I tried with text:split(",") but it splits only "," i dont know how to add "and" pattern.

Comment: First replace `" and"` by `","`.

Comment: That is not what i need, something like split (","+"and") but idk how patters should look correctly.

Comment: `s = "one, two, three and four"; for w in s:gsub("%s*,%s*", "\0"):gsub("%s*%f[%w_]and%f[^%w_]%s*", "\0"):gmatch"%Z+" do print(w) end`

Comment: Working thanks, but there should be shorter way i believe.